# How to use ampersand (&) symbol inside jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-entities, ampersand

I have a `<select>` menu with a bunch of `<option>` tags, all populated from a database table.

I need to use a jquery selector such as `$('option[value=d&c]')` in order to find an option such as this one:

```
<option value="d&c">d&amp;c</option>
```

Note that the `value` attribute does not have an encoded ampersand (`&amp;`) in it, just a straight ampersand (`&`) because of how Zend Framework populates it.

Only problem is that jQuery chokes with the following error:

```
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value=d&c]
```

It also won't accept `$('option[value=d&amp;c]')`. It's the ampersand messing it up, in either case. Does anyone know how to get around this limitation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You missed the quotes around the value

This works:

```
$('option[value="d&c"]')
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8H2g/)

Comment: Both this and the escaped version work, however I give points to the quoted value= because that's the preferred syntax via: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: So simple, and yet I just couldn't think of it. Thanks!

Comment: That's not the preferred syntax.. Check the bold text under value description that says "value - An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string. "

Comment: @SKS - I would say it's preferable considering all of their own examples use the quote syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Try escaping it...

```
$('option[value=d\\&c]')
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Np4xB/).

...or use quotes, which is recommended in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It works when you set the option value in quotes:

```
$(function() {
    alert($("option[value='d&c']").text());       
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fGTRv/